# what information is collected when scraping google search result using urllib2

Tags: web-scraping, urllib2, google-search

Scraping newbie here.
I’m trying to scraping Google Search Result using urllib2 & beautifulsoup like below.

```
domain_to_filter = 'www.google.com'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
for start in range(start_page, (start_page + pages)):
    url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&start=%s" % (query, str(start * 10))
    page = opener.open(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
```

My question is:
what information of my side Google would get, if I do this.

I understand they will get my IP address.
What else information do they get? Can they get my google ID, if I'm logged on google on the agent(firefox or chrome)? Or even worse, can they get the Microsoft Account ID if I'm using Window as OS and logged on Window10?

Comment: No, what happens in the browser has nothing to do with any request you make in python, where do you think this info would be stored in the request?